# Setting rendered attribute to a value expression on a component programmatically in JSF

Tags: jsf

How to set `rendered` attribute to a value expression on a JSF component? The `UIComponentBase` class does not have a method `setRendered(ValueExpression ve)`. It only has `setRendered(boolean)`.

Code example:

```java
HtmlCommandLink cmdLink = Faces.createComponent(HtmlCommandLink.COMPONENT_TYPE);
cmdLink.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{commonDAO.getDataFile(" + valueExpr +").name}"));
cmdLink.setActionExpression(createMethodExpression("#{dataFileBean.serveDownload(" + valueExpr +")}"));

// THIS ONE DOES NOT EXISTS !!! THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO.
cmdLink.setRenderedToExpression(createValueExpression("#{not empty " + valueExpr + "}"));

fileLine.getChildren().add(cmdLink);
```

Comment: Have you tried `cmdLink.setValueExpression("rendered", createValueExpression(...))` at all? Basically the same as you already did for the `value` attribute.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks! That worked. I wrote this code 10 year ago and the method name `setValueExpression` with `"value"` parameter confused me. I mistakenly thought it is only for setting the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
cmdLink.setValueExpression("rendered", createValueExpression("#{not empty " + valueExpr + "}"));
```